# Google App Engine Java Aplication: DB Migration

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, data-migration

I follow this steps from API Google App Engine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#Copying_Entities_to_Another_Application

1. With Python SDK, I deploy the datastore_admin app: *appcfg.py -A APPID update DIRECTORYOFDATASTOREADMINAPP*
2. In the Dashboard, I select the entities and press *Copy to Another App* entering the remote endpoint: https://ANHORTHERAPPID.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api

I get the following error: "There was a problem kicking off the jobs. The error was: Fetch to https://ANHORTHERAPPID.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api failed with status 404"

Any help? I'm totally lost :-(

Comment: Is remote_api enabled for your target application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

1. You must be owner (role) in both applications (origin and destination)
2. You must edit the datastore_admin app (download it at first link in my post) and edit the files:

   - app.yaml: ID of destination app
   - appengine_config.py: ID of origin app
3. Deploy the datastore_admin app in both apps:

   - *appcfg.py -A APPIDORIGIN update DIRECTORYOFDATASTOREADMINAPP*
   - *appcfg.py -A APPIDDESTINATION update DIRECTORYOFDATASTOREADMINAPP*

Full solution in spanish: http://www.megustaprogramar.com/2012/08/migracion-de-datos-bajo-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a small, but critical item I missed, the files (app.yaml and appengine_config.py) have to be copied into the root directory of your Java project, not the war directory, but the very top directory.

I missed this point and when I ran appcfg.py it gave me the error:

```
appcfg.py: error: Directory does not contain an app.yaml configuration file.
```

After including the files everything went great, thanks!